# PostgreSQL INSERT multiple JSONB columns for record

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, jsonb, postgres-14

I am unable to insert multiple python dict into separate JSONB columns for a new record (auto ID) for one cur.execute using python with pyscopg2.  I am able to insert each dict individually, but without specifying an ID, it creates new records.

### Create Dictionaries and Table:

```
dict1 = {"dict1Key1":"dict1value1", "dict1Key2":"dict1value2"}
dict2 = {"dict2Key1":"dict2value1", "dict2Key2":"dict2value2"}

query_test_jsonb_many = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_test_jsonb_many (id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, col1_jsonb JSONB, col2_jsonb JSONB);"""

try:
    with psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, user=user,
                                password=password, port=port, host=host) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query_test_jsonb_many)
        print(query_test_jsonb_many)
        con.commit()
        
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print("Fail to execute due to the error:", e)

print("==============")
print("dict1: " + str(dict1))
print("dict1 Type is: " + str(type(dict1)))
print("==============")
print("dict2: " + str(dict2))
print("dict1 Type is: " + str(type(dict1)))
print("==============")
```

### Successfully load dict1 > col1_jsonb and dict2 > col2_jsonb individually

```
try:
    with psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, user=user,
                                password=password, port=port, host=host) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute(f'''INSERT INTO table_test_jsonb_many (col1_jsonb) VALUES (%s::jsonb);''',([json.dumps(dict(dict1))]))
        cur.execute(f'''INSERT INTO table_test_jsonb_many (col2_jsonb) VALUES (%s::jsonb);''',([json.dumps(dict(dict2))]))
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print("Fail to execute due to the error:", e)
```

### Fail to load dict1 > col1_jsonb and dict2 > col2_jsonb in one query execute command

```
try:
    with psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, user=user,
                                password=password, port=port, host=host) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute(f'''INSERT INTO table_test_jsonb_many (col1_jsonb, col2_jsonb) VALUES (%s::jsonb, %s::jsonb);''',([json.dumps(dict(dict1))],[json.dumps(dict(dict2))]))
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print("Fail to execute due to the error:", e)
```

[screenshot of pgadmin query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLNf7.png)

Comment: `([json.dumps(dict(dict1))],[json.dumps(dict(dict2))])`: there's no need to wrap each part with a list, or to call `dict` on what is already a dict. Passing  `(json.dumps(dict1) ,json.dumps(dict2))` will work fine to insert in both columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `psycopg2` built in [JSON adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json) and do:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import Json 

cur.execute("INSERT INTO table_test_jsonb_many (col1_jsonb, col2_jsonb) VALUES (%s, %s)",[Json(dict1), Json(dict2)])
```

Notes:

1. Do not use `F` strings and in this case it was not needed anyway.
2. No need for `%s::jsonb`, the type adaption is handled by `psycopg2`
3. Use the `psycopg2` JSON adapter `Json` to properly adapt the dicts.